# DataTables JS / TableTools JS - exporting and printing

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I am using dataTables (http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js) & tableTools (http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js & http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css) and displaying a table and want to print it. But am having problems with the same.

Here are my options

```
 $("#reportTableId").DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "sDom": 'Tlrt',
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": "../ed1/static/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends": "collection",
                        "sButtonText": "Save",
                        "aButtons": [
                            {
                                "sExtends": "xls",
                                "sTitle": $Name
                            },
                            {
                                "sExtends": "pdf",
                                "sTitle": $Name
                            }
                        ],
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2],
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape"
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "print",
                        "mColumns": "visible"
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
```

My report html structure is in the following format

```
    <table id="reportTableId">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e" colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
   .tg-031ea {
        width: 15%;
    }
```

1. When I try to export to Excel, I get only the 1st columns, don't get the second;
2. In excel no cell colors are exported
3. In PDF I get only 1 page output thought the report HTML is 13 pages. I have tried to include columns, but no success.

Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML output:
[image: HTML snapshot]

PDF output: (only the heading column)
[image: pdf output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is not too late, from my previous experience, I have learnt that Datatables requires valud HTML table, so having a colspan in your table does not help.

Comment: Thanks, found it the hard way, but you are right, I had to remove the colspan and now its working.